Equivalence of a function to its truncated power series
Here I apply the same formulas to the function $e^{-x}$ and its truncated power series. Why is the second result so different from the others?

Code text:
f[x_] := 
 1 - x + x^2/2 - x^3/6 + x^4/24 - x^5/120 + x^6/720 - x^7/5040 + x^8/
  40320 - x^9/362880 + x^10/3628800 - x^11/39916800 + x^12/479001600 -
   x^13/6227020800 + x^14/87178291200 - x^15/1307674368000 + x^16/
  20922789888000 - x^17/355687428096000 + x^18/6402373705728000 - 
  x^19/121645100408832000 + x^20/2432902008176640000
g[x_] := Exp[-x]

f[0] + Sum[f[x + 1] - f[ x], {x, 0, \[Infinity]}, 
   Regularization -> "Dirichlet"] // N
g[0] + Sum[g[x + 1] - g[ x], {x, 0, \[Infinity]}, 
   Regularization -> "Dirichlet"] // N
Integrate[f[x], {x, 0, 1}] // N
Integrate[g[x], {x, 0, 1}] // N


Please show us the code text, the question will be reopened once it meets the standard of the site.

@xzczd my bad. done

$Version

(* "14.1.0 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (July 16, 2024)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

f[x_] = Series[E^-x, {x, 0, 20}] // Normal;

g[x_] := E^-x

f[0] + Sum[f[x + 1] - f[x], {x, 0, \[Infinity]}, 
   Regularization -> "Dirichlet"] // N

(* 0.632121 *)

g[0] + Sum[g[x + 1] - g[x], {x, 0, \[Infinity]}, Regularization -> "Cesaro"]

(* 0 *)

Note that this sum is not divergent and regularization is not needed.
g[0] + Sum[g[x + 1] - g[x], {x, 0, \[Infinity]}]

(* 0 *)

f and g are not equal. For the later elements of the sums they differ radically.
LogPlot[{f[x], g[x]}, {x, 0, 10},
 PlotStyle -> {Automatic, Dashed},
 AxesLabel -> {Style[x, 14], None},
 PlotLegends -> Placed["Expressions", {.5, .7}]]


f and g are equal in the interval [0, 1] so the two integrals are equal.
Integrate[f[x], {x, 0, 1}] // N

(* 0.632121 *)

Integrate[g[x], {x, 0, 1}] // N

(* 0.632121 *)


The thing is, Integrate[f[x], {x, 0, 1}] should be equal to f[0] + Sum[f[x + 1] - f[x], {x, 0, \[Infinity]},Regularization -> "Dirichlet"] for all functions. Why does it coincide for the partial series only?

Notice also that the first result does not change if we increase the number of terms in the truncated series. It is roughly the same for 50, 100 and 101 terms, so in the limit should be the same.

@Annix, your statement  can not be true unless some conditions on the function is imposed. In particular, second result (zero) is correct. As well as the fourth.

If $\sum a_n$ be convergent, then $a_0 + \sum_{n=0} (a_{n+1}-a_n)$ will be telescoping and converge to zero. Regularization does not change this. Hence the result for g[x].
OTOH, for a polynomial $f_d$ of degree $d$, $\sum f_d(n)$ is divergent and the Dirichlet sum $\sum f_d(n)/n^s$ is divergent for $Re(s) \le d$. Regularization extends, or attempts to extend, the sum to $s \rightarrow 0$. If $\lim_{d \rightarrow \infty} f_d(x) = g(x)$, it does not follow, although it could be true, that $$\lim_{d \rightarrow \infty} \lim_{s \rightarrow 0} \sum f_d(n)/n^s 
\buildrel {?} \over = 
\lim_{s \rightarrow 0} \sum \lim_{d \rightarrow \infty} f_d(n)/n^s= 
\lim_{s \rightarrow 0} \sum g(n)/n^s \,.$$
This does not explain why the result for f[x] is different; rather, it explains why a different result is not surprising.
There is a Wolfram blog post by Devendra Kapadia, https://blog.wolfram.com/2014/08/06/the-abcd-of-divergent-series/,
that shows some of the strange things that happen with Dirichlet regularization of divergent series.
